# Django Channels group send only sends the message to last channel

Tags: python, django, django-channels

I'm working on django channels-3.0.3, the `group_send` only sends my message to the last connected channel to the connected users times.

settings

```
...
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    "django.contrib.admin",
    "django.contrib.auth",
    "django.contrib.contenttypes",
    "django.contrib.sessions",
    "django.contrib.messages",
    "django.contrib.staticfiles",
    "chat",
    "channels",
]

ASGI_APPLICATION = "cfehome.routing.application"

CHANNEL_LAYERS = {
    "default": {
        "BACKEND": "channels_redis.core.RedisChannelLayer",
        "CONFIG": {
            "hosts": [("127.0.0.1", 6379)],
        },
    },
}
```

chat/consumers.py

```
import asyncio
import json
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from channels.consumer import AsyncConsumer
from channels.db import database_sync_to_async

from .models import Thread, ChatMessage


class ChatConsumer(AsyncConsumer):
    @database_sync_to_async
    def get_thread(self, user, other_username):
        return Thread.objects.get_or_new(user, other_username)[0]

    async def websocket_connect(self, event):
        other_user = self.scope['url_route']['kwargs']['username']
        me = self.scope['user']
        # print("connect!")
        # print(me, other_user)
        thread_obj = await self.get_thread(me, other_user)
        # print(me, thread_obj)
        chat_room = f"thread_{thread_obj.id}"
        self.chat_room = chat_room
        await self.channel_layer.group_add(
            chat_room,
            self.channel_name
        )
        print(f"{self.channel_name}, {self.chat_room}, {me} - connected!")
        await self.send({
            "type": "websocket.accept"
        })

    async def websocket_receive(self, event):
        print("msg recevied!", event)
        front_text = event.get("text", None)
        if front_text is not None:
            loaded_dic_Data = json.loads(front_text)
            msg = loaded_dic_Data.get("message")
            # print(msg)
            user = self.scope['user']
            username = "default"
            if user.is_authenticated:
                username = user.username
            myResponse = {
                "message": msg,
                "username": username
            }

            # brodcast msg to chatroom
            await self.channel_layer.group_send(
                self.chat_room,
                {
                    "type": "chat_message",
                    "text": json.dumps(myResponse),
                }
            )

    #  sends the actual msg
    async def chat_message(self, event):
        await self.send({
            "type": "websocket.send",
            "text": event["text"]

        })

    async def websocket_disconnect(self, event):
        print("disconnect!")
        await self.channel_layer.group_discard(
            self.chat_room,
            self.channel_name
        )
```

in consumers.py i aslo tried `async_to_sync` instated of `async` and `await`

chat/templates/chat/threads.html (my template which renders)

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block content %}
<h3>Thread for {% if user != object.first %}{{ object.first }}{% else %}{{ object.second }}{% endif %}</h3>
<ul id='chat-items'>
{% for chat in object.chatmessage_set.all %}

<li>{{ chat.message }} via {{ chat.user }}</li>

{% endfor %}
</ul>

<form id='form' method='POST'> {% csrf_token %}
    <input type="hidden" id="myUsername" value="{{ user.username }}">
{{form.as_p }}
<input type='submit' class='btn btn-primary'/>
</form>

{% endblock %}

{% block script %}

<script>
// websocket scripts
var loc = window.location;

var formData = $("#form")
var msg = $("#id_message")
var chatHoler = $("#chat-items")
var me = $("#myUsername").val()

var wsStart = "ws://";
if(loc.protocol == "https:"){
    wsStart = "wss://"
};
var endpoint =  wsStart + loc.host + loc.pathname;
var socket = new WebSocket(endpoint);

console.log(endpoint)

socket.onmessage = function(e){
    console.log("message ",e)
    var chatDataMsg = JSON.parse(e.data)
    chatHoler.append("<li>" + chatDataMsg.message + "  -  " + chatDataMsg.username + "</li>")
};
socket.onopen = function(e){
    console.log("open ",e)
    formData.submit(function(event){
        event.preventDefault()
        var msgText = msg.val()
        // chatHoler.append("<li>" + msgText + " via " + me +"</li>")

        var finalData = {
            "message": msgText,
        }
        socket.send(JSON.stringify(finalData))
        formData[0].reset()
    });
};
socket.onerror = function(e){
    console.log("error ",e)
};
socket.onclose = function(e){
    console.log("close ",e)
};

</script>
{% endblock %}
```

it receive the message from a channel and send back to that channel to the number of connected channels in chat_room.

*~ thanks in advance.. it's my first question on site :)*

**updated!** here is my routing.py file

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from channels.routing import ProtocolTypeRouter, URLRouter
from channels.auth import AuthMiddlewareStack
from channels.security.websocket import AllowedHostsOriginValidator, OriginValidator

from chat.consumers import ChatConsumer

application = ProtocolTypeRouter({
    "websocket": AllowedHostsOriginValidator(
        AuthMiddlewareStack(
            URLRouter(
                [
                    url(r"^messages/(?P<username>[\w.@+-]+)/$", ChatConsumer()),
                ]
            )
        )
    )
})
```

Comment: I also experienced this issue it was with my routing file. Can you share your routing.py file?

Comment: hi sir thanks for soon replay, I updated the question and that's my routing.py file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

1. Import `get_asgi_application` from `django.core.asgi`.
2. allow Django's ASGI application to handle traditional `http` requests by adding `http` as key & `get_asgi_application()` as the value of key in the dictionary inside `ProtocolTypeRouter`.
3. use/call the `as_asgi()` classmethod while routing the `ChatConsumer` consumer.

**routing.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.core.asgi import get_asgi_application #Change No.1

from channels.routing import ProtocolTypeRouter, URLRouter
from channels.auth import AuthMiddlewareStack
from channels.security.websocket import AllowedHostsOriginValidator, OriginValidator

from chat.consumers import ChatConsumer

application = ProtocolTypeRouter({
    "http": get_asgi_application(), #Change No.2
    "websocket": AllowedHostsOriginValidator(
        AuthMiddlewareStack(
            URLRouter([
                url(r"^messages/(?P<username>[\w.@+-]+)/$", ChatConsumer.as_asgi()), #Change No.3
           ])
        )
    )
})
```

More Information on [channels.readthedocs.io](https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/stable/topics/routing.html).

Comment: Thaaannnk you so much Sir <3 yeah it's working, i were struggling 3days on. That's it.